# Aggregator, UDAFs and types

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to apply a UDAF to a dataframe in order to get an estimation of the possible types inside a df column. I have been able to achieve the following:

```
case class EstimateTypes[A]() 
    extends Aggregator[A, Map[String, Int], Map[String, Int]] with Serializable {      
    
    def zero: Map[String, Int] = Map() // Init the buffer
  
    def reduce(y: Map[String, Int], x: A) = FunEstimateType(y, x)

    def merge(a: Map[String, Int], b: Map[String, Int]) = a ++ b.map{ case (k,v) => k -> (v + a.getOrElse(k,0)) }

    def finish(r: Map[String, Int]) = r
  
    def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Map[String, Int]] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[Map[String, Int]])

    def outputEncoder: Encoder[Map[String, Int]] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[Map[String, Int]])
}

def my_udaf[A: TypeTag](col: org.apache.spark.sql.Column) = {
  val meanUdaf = udaf(new EstimateTypes[A]())
  meanUdaf(col)
  }

val my_cols = Seq("id", "value")
val df = Seq(
  ("Hi", "2023-02-13"), ("Hi", "asdasd"),
  ("Hi", "2023-02-13"), ("Hi", "2023-02-13"),
).toDF("id", "value")

df.select(my_cols.map(c => my_udaf[String](col(c)).alias(c)): _*).show()

+-------------+--------------------+
|           id|               value|
+-------------+--------------------+
|{String -> 4}|{date -> 3, Strin...|
+-------------+--------------------+
```

However, if I want to expand this, I need to use each column type as the type of my_udaf, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just expanded on the `FunEstimateType` function to make it more generic so that it can switch and based on the custom data type that is present in the current column that is getting parsed, it will evaluate the result.

So, it goes as follows:

```scala
def FunEstimateType(y: Map[String, Int], x: Any): Map[String, Int] = {
  x match {
    case _: String => y.updated("String", y.getOrElse("String", 0) + 1)
    case _: Int => y.updated("Int", y.getOrElse("Int", 0) + 1)
    case _: Double => y.updated("Double", y.getOrElse("Double", 0) + 1)
    case _: Boolean => y.updated("Boolean", y.getOrElse("Boolean", 0) + 1)
    case _ => y
  }
}
```

Here `y` is a map where the keys are string representations of data types ("String", "Int", "Double", "Boolean") and the `values` are counts of how many times each type has been encountered. `x` is a value of any type that is being checked and counted.

Then, I defined a `switchUdafByType` that will give an instance of the `EstimateTypes` case class and apply the UDAF to the particular  column of the corresponding type. (e.g. `Int`, `String` etc.)

```scala
def switchUdafByType[A: TypeTag](col: Column): Column = {
  val my_udaf_instance = udaf(new EstimateTypes[A]())
  my_udaf_instance(col)
}
```

To utilize this function and apply it over the columns iteratively, I devised the following:

```scala
val exprs = df.schema.fields.map { field =>
  field.dataType match {
    case StringType => switchUdafByType[String](col(field.name)).as(field.name)
    case IntegerType => switchUdafByType[Int](col(field.name)).as(field.name)
    case DoubleType => switchUdafByType[Double](col(field.name)).as(field.name)
    case BooleanType => switchUdafByType[Boolean](col(field.name)).as(field.name)
    case _ => col(field.name) // if the type doesn't match any of the above, I leave the column unchanged
  }
}
```

The overall code then becomes:

```scala
// Imports
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame, Encoder, SparkSession}

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("testRun").master("local").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

// Define the FunEstimateType function
def FunEstimateType(y: Map[String, Int], x: Any): Map[String, Int] = {
  x match {
    case _: String => y.updated("String", y.getOrElse("String", 0) + 1)
    case _: Int => y.updated("Int", y.getOrElse("Int", 0) + 1)
    case _: Double => y.updated("Double", y.getOrElse("Double", 0) + 1)
    case _: Boolean => y.updated("Boolean", y.getOrElse("Boolean", 0) + 1)
    case _ => y
  }
}

// Custom Aggregator
case class EstimateTypes[A]() extends Aggregator[A, Map[String, Int], Map[String, Int]] with Serializable {
  def zero: Map[String, Int] = Map() // Init the buffer

  def reduce(y: Map[String, Int], x: A): Map[String, Int] = FunEstimateType(y, x)

  def merge(a: Map[String, Int], b: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int] = a ++ b.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + a.getOrElse(k, 0)) }

  def finish(r: Map[String, Int]): Map[String, Int] = r

  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Map[String, Int]] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[Map[String, Int]])

  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Map[String, Int]] = implicitly(ExpressionEncoder[Map[String, Int]])
}

// Define the UDAF function which switches by type of column & column
def switchUdafByType[A: TypeTag](col: Column): Column = {
  val my_udaf_instance = udaf(new EstimateTypes[A]())
  my_udaf_instance(col)
}

// Create a DataFrame
val df: DataFrame = Seq(("Hi", 2023, 13.0, true), ("Hello", 2024, 14.0, false), ("Hey", 2025, 15.0, true), ("Hola", 2026, 16.0, false)).toDF("id", "year", "value", "flag")

// Apply the UDAF to each column based on its type
val exprs = df.schema.fields.map { field =>
  field.dataType match {
    case StringType => switchUdafByType[String](col(field.name)).as(field.name)
    case IntegerType => switchUdafByType[Int](col(field.name)).as(field.name)
    case DoubleType => switchUdafByType[Double](col(field.name)).as(field.name)
    case BooleanType => switchUdafByType[Boolean](col(field.name)).as(field.name)
    case _ => col(field.name) // if the type doesn't match any of the above, leave the column unchanged
  }
}
val new_df: DataFrame = df.select(exprs: _*)


// display input
print("input data")
df.show(false)

// display output
print("output data")
new_df.show(false)
```

For the following input:

```
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|id   |year|value|flag |
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|Hi   |2023|13.0 |true |
|Hello|2024|14.0 |false|
|Hey  |2025|15.0 |true |
|Hola |2026|16.0 |false|
+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

It generate this output:

```
+-------------+----------+-------------+--------------+
|id           |year      |value        |flag          |
+-------------+----------+-------------+--------------+
|{String -> 4}|{Int -> 4}|{Double -> 4}|{Boolean -> 4}|
+-------------+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!! I will have a look as soon as I can.